# Restore default permissions to "/var" to CentOS installation

Tags: linux, permissions, centos, chmod

So I accidentally ran `chmod -R 0777 /var` and I need to revert that (let alone allow chmod the correct ssh directory so I can log back into it). I'm feeling screwed, can anyone help? The sooner the better, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is for *var*

drwxr-xr-x  21 root root  4096 Apr  6  2011 var

and for '*var/**' subfolders on my host (CentOS 6)

```
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4096 Apr  2  2011 cache
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep  3  2009 cvs
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 26  2010 db
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Mar 15  2011 empty
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Mar 15  2011 ftp
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 26  2010 games
drwxr-xr-x 21 root root 4096 Apr  6  2011 lib
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 26  2010 local
drwxrwxr-x  5 root lock 4096 Apr  5 04:02 lock
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4096 Apr  5 04:02 log
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   10 Mar 15  2011 mail -> spool/mail
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 26  2010 nis
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 26  2010 opt
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 26  2010 preserve
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4096 Feb  2 07:39 run
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Mar 15  2011 spool
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Apr  9  2011 svn
drwxrwxrwt  4 root root 4096 Jan 31 19:58 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4096 Mar 15  2011 www
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 26  2010 yp
```

Answer (score 0):

All your files are now executable as well in all subdirectories to `/var`. This could be solved by e.g. `find` and `chmod`, but it is difficult to know which ones were supposed to be executable to begin with.

On my system, the few executable files below `/var` are

- the ones ending with

  - .preinst
  - .prerm
  - .postinst
  - .postrm

  in `/var/lib/dpkg/info`,
- `/var/lib/apt-xapian-index/update-lock`
- `/var/lib/shorewall/.restore`
- `/var/lib/shorewall/.restart`
- `/var/lib/shorewall/firewall`
- `/var/lib/shorewall/.start`
- `/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/295.33/build/conftest.sh`

If **I** had to restore **the executable bit** after `sudo chmod 777 -R /var`, I could thus run

```
sudo find /var -type f -exec chmod -x {} +
```

and then manually set `chmod +x` on the files I listed above, ***but*** you will also have problems restoring permissions on files and directories that previously were completely forbidden for *anyone* (but root) to read, which concerns many more files.

The lasting problem is security, but mostly if someone is able to log in as a regular user on the computer. If it's a single user system with a low threat level, you could probably keep going and just take it as a lesson. Had it been something else, a re-install would be the simplest way to fix everything.

Permissions are central in file handling on *nix. It's a quite destructive operation to completely wipe all of them on a fundamental directory tree; and thus quite difficult to restore as well.